# How do I include an ID number into a URL in a dynamic way and display the content on the page?

Tags: php, wordpress, include, echo

I have a WordPress site that is allowed to display data from another site and I've created the PHP echo statement correctly to display the content.
But the Read More URL scheme is thus: ?more_url_scheme=/job_order/{id}/
When I click on Read More I go to the correct Job_order page, but obviously nothing shows because the {id} number isn't included.

1. How do I include the ID number, and therefore display this content? Is it a wildcard setting?
2. OR do I just create a PHP request on the job_order page which then grabs the ID from the session/previous page and then displays the content?

I've tried multiple approaches and I'm not getting anywhere and it's probably super obvious but I can't brain right now so help!

I am expecting to A) view the jobs on one page (working as expected) and B) click on read more and go to the page where the job content is displayed, but it isn't displaying and the ID is getting lost or something.

Comment: Are you parsing $_GET to extract the ID from the URL? It appears you're using a path/string and not passing the ID as a stand-alone value.